# Share same method precondition logic between controllers and services?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, design-patterns, preconditions

I have a `Service` and a `Controller` .

Each method in the service its preconditions , for example :

```
  public void doSomething(Parameter para1 , Parameter para2 ...) {
    if ( something wrong ) {
      throw new RuntimeException1();
    }
    if ( another thing wrong ) {
      throw new RuntimeException2();
    }
    // continue do something 
  }
```

And in the Controller layer , there are two methods , one is `showForm()` which displays form for user to input ;  another is `doApplyForm()` which accepts form and calls the underlaying `Service.doSomething()`.

The following is the pseudo code (I eliminated some `BindingResult` , `attr.addFlashAttribute` codes ) :

```
  @Injected Service service;

  public String showForm() {
    if ( something wrong ) {
      throw new RuntimeException1();
    }
    if ( another thing wrong ) {
      throw new RuntimeException2();
    }
    return "showForm";
  }

  public String doApplyForm(@Validated Form form) {
    try {
      service.doSomething(para1 , para2 ...);
      return "redirect:/";
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // error handling 
      return "redirect:/error";
    }
  }
```

It works well , but I am not satisfied. There're **bad smells** within.

The problem is in the `showForm()` , which shares identical preconditions with `Controller.doSomething()` .

If `Service.doSomething()` add another preconditions in the future , `Controller.showForm()` has to do correspondent changes.

I wonder if there're any design pattern or frameworks to eliminate such **bad smell** ?

Java8's functional solutions are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a util class called `Preconditions` and move all your validation logic there. It's a common pattern and there are a number of frameworks that make use of it. For example, Guava: [Preconditions docs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html).

At least like this your `if (condition) throw new exception` will be capsulated and easier to manage.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a parameter object for the service request and put the validation logic into the request object. E.g.

```
public class DoSomethingRequest {

   private Parameter param1;
   private Parameter param2;


   public void validate(){
       if ( something wrong ) {
           throw new RuntimeException1();
       }
       if ( another thing wrong ) {
           throw new RuntimeException2();
       }
   }

}
```

Your service will be more easy

```
public void doSomething(DoSomethingRequest request) {
    request.validate();
}
```

so the controller

```
public String showForm() {
    DoSomethingRequest request = ... // obtained somehow
    request.validate();
    // ...
    return "showForm";
}
```

This encapsulates the service method's preconditions in an object.